# Regex for checking binary transferred ASCII space In Bash

Tags: linux, windows, bash, csv, scripting

I'm copying a csv file from windows to linux in binary mode.
And in bash I want to validate the content, with specific character set like alphanumeric and some special chars.

```
re='^[-a-zA-Z0-9. ,\/()&_]*$'
if [[ ! $line =~ $re ]] 
then
    echo "Found undefined character in :$line"
    break
fi
```

on sending a line ...

```
ABCD EFG, ABCD EFG, ABCD EFG
```

regx not recognizing the space. since it was copied from windows in binary mode.
moment when i give them linux space. regx recognizing it as a space.

how to handle this?
i can't change the transfer mode to ascii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow for optional `\r` (DOS line end) at the end of your input you can use this regex:

```
re=$'^[-a-zA-Z0-9. ,/()&_]+\r?$'
```

Now test it:

```
line=$'ABCD EFG, ABCD EFG, ABCD EFG\r'
[[ $line =~ $re ]] && echo "valid" || echo "invalid"
```

**Output:**

```
valid
```

Comment: yeah, its working fine. and I m surprised to know that its not the space creating the problem, rather line end. Also I don't understand the reason why $ to be included at the beginning and ? inserted at the end.

Comment: `\r?` makes `\r` optional in regex. `$''` is BASH syntax to include `\n` or `\r` in your input literally.